# Anyone know how i can fix this issue?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I cant create app on heroku.

I am trying to create a 1 click strapi heroku app with cloudinary.
I have bought postgress mini.

But get this error message.

Anyone know what i can do?

I am trying to create an app on heroku.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUEmu.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUCJP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might have subscribed to paid Heroku services on your other apps, but [the `app.json` in the repository you are trying to deploy](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-heroku-template/blob/master/app.json) still tries to use a free PostgreSQL database:

```json
"addons": [
  "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"
],
```

Since Heroku no longer provides a `hobby-dev` PostgreSQL tier, I suggest you fork the repository on GitHub and change the addons in that file:

```json
"addons": [
  "heroku-postgresql:mini"
],
```

(Of course, this will incur the costs of a [mini-tier](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql#pricing) Heroku Postgres database.)

Then deploy from your fork.